# Slick Slider Stuck at the default number of slides

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider, shopify, slick.js

I have implemented a slider, but it shows 3 slides for every screen size even after a page refresh.

this is the jQuery code that implements the slider

```
$(".slider").slick({
  dots: false,
  infinite: true,
  speed: 500,
  slidesToShow: 1,
  slidesToScroll: 1,
  mobileFirst: true,
  responsive: [
    {
      breakpoint: 968,
      settings: {
        slidesToShow: 3,
        slidesToScroll: 3,
      }
    },
    {
      breakpoint: 600,
      settings: {
        slidesToShow: 2,
        slidesToScroll: 2
      }
    },
    {
      breakpoint: 480,
      settings: {
        slidesToShow: 1,
        slidesToScroll: 1
      }
    }
  ],
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$(".slider").slick({
  dots: false,
  infinite: true,
  speed: 500,
  slidesToShow: 1,
  slidesToScroll: 1,
  responsive: [
    {
      breakpoint: 900,
      settings: {
        slidesToShow: 2,
        slidesToScroll: 2,
      },
    },
    {
      breakpoint: 480,
      settings: {
        slidesToShow: 1,
        slidesToScroll: 1,
      },
    },
  ]
   });
```

Comment: not working for me, it shows me a single  item on every screen size